# Pentaho text file input step crashing (out of memory)

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am using Pentaho for reading a very large file. 11GB.

The process is sometime crashing with out of memory exception, and sometimes it will just say process killed.

I am running the job on a machine with 12GB, and giving the process 8 GB.

Is there a way to run the Text File Input step with some configuration to use less memory? maybe use the disk more?

[image: Transformation]

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include a screen shot of your transformation including all used components?

Comment: Per Marcus Rickert request I have added a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Open up spoon.sh/bat or pan/kettle .sh or .bat and change the -Xmx figure.  Search for JAVAMAXMEM Even though you have spare memory unless java is allowed to use it it wont work.  although to be fair in your example above i can't really see why/how it would be consuming much memory anyway!