# Low performance Pentaho BI Server

Tags: performance, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I'm starting my data warehouse, and I am using Pentaho data integration, Mondrian and Pentaho bi server. The database is MySQL but I've tried PostgreSQL. But my dashboard is with a very low performance. Unfortunately I can not increase much my physical resources. I thought of loading the cache previously (precache), but I do not know if it will be the best solution. Thank you

Comment: can you tell me what is the version of Pentaho you are using ?? Also what is the OS configuration ?

Comment: Pentaho data integration -> 5.1.0
Mondrian -> 3.7.0.0-752
Pentaho bi server -> 5.1.0.0.752

Running:
 - Centos-7
 - Ram:8GB
 - HD:100GB
 - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5420 @ 2.50GHz

P.S. My data has actually 4GB

Comment: The configurations looks great !!!.. Can you try increasing the java memory "JAVAMAXMEM" . Something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091308/pentaho-text-file-input-step-crashing-out-of-memory/27100624#27100624 ... Since the data volume is huge.. i assume it might be slowing down the perf. a bit !! just give it a try !! :)

Answer (score 0):

How big is your DWH? How many rows do the fact and dimension tables contains.

Optimize your current DWH following the recommendations for database tuning ([Mondrian Performance](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/performance.php)). Identify slowest queries on dashboards and use Mondrian aggregate tables for them (use [Pentaho Aggregation Designer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mondrian/files/aggregation%20designer/) for creating them).

Alternatively if you use the Pentaho BI server CE try to use CDC ([Community Distributed Cache](http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/cdc/)) to precache some cubes etc. after loading fresh data to DWH as a last step of your ETL process.

The third option is to consider switching from a row oriented db (MySQL, PostreSQL) to a column oriented db ([MonetDB](https://www.monetdb.org/Home), [Vertica](http://www.pentaho.com/pentaho-and-hp-vertica-analytics)).